# Problem to show surjectivity in general

Tags: real-analysis

I hava problem to show surjectivity in general. Let $$f:A\longrightarrow B$$ a function. To prove it is surjective, I have to prove that for all $y\in B$, there is an $x\in A$ such that $y=f(x)$. So let take a simple exemple,

**1)** $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^+$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$. A proof in my book is, $$x=y^2\implies y= \sqrt x$$ and thus it's surjective. I absolutely don't understand this argument... Wouldn't it be better to say that if $y>0$, then $$y=(\sqrt y)^2=f(\sqrt y)$$
and thus, if we set $x=\sqrt y\in\mathbb R$, we have the result ?

**2)** Same for $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^+$ defined by $f(x)=e^x$. My book says that $$x=e^y\iff y=\ln(x)$$ and thus it's surjective. The argument looks strange... Wouldn't be better to say if $y>0$ then, $$y=e^{\ln(y)}=f(\ln(y))$$
and thus, if we set $x=\ln(y)$, we have the result.

I know my question looks obvious, but I really have problem with this.

Comment: I agree; your proofs look preferable to your book's arguments, since they use $x$ and $y$ consistently throughout. It's as if your book exchanged $x$ and $y$ before inverting, as is often done in American precalculus courses to uphold the convention that "$x$ is the input and $y$ is the output".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof in your book is "short form" of your proof, and it's totally equivalent to your proof. Your understand surjectivity pretty well.